# emberJS with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js, asp.net-web-api, ember-cli

I'm trying to combine a MVC project to EmberJS. I searched for existed questions but I only came this far by those:  I created something with `ember new emberProject`and wrote simple templates, routes, models, mirage etc. Then I created an MVC web API and in the controllers, I created AppController and write this:

```
 public class AppController : Controller
    {
        // GET: App
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return File(Server.MapPath("~/emberProject/dist/") + "index.html", "text/html");
        }
    }
```

and for the index I write the path:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/emberProject/dist/assets/vendor.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do after this? Shouldn't I see my `.hbs` and `.js` files on the MVC project? Because I can't. Also, right now I'm using hard-coded dummy data. I need to take data from MVC in order to use as a "model" on my ember project. What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its strongly recommended by the ember community to keep your frontend application and your API backend separated. This is also a requirement if you want to use `ember-cli`

So you would only use your asp.NET MVC application to serve your data and your static assets. For development you would start your `ember-cli` project with `ember serve --proxy=http://your-asp.net_mvcproject/`, so that all API requests are proxied to your asp.NET Backend.

Then you should create a API in your asp.NET MVS project to access your data, I recommend to use the [`JSONAPI`](http://jsonapi.org), which is the ember default implementation.

Then you can build your client application only with `ember-cli`, without asp.NET MVC, only getting your data from your backend.

The integration is then only required for deployment, where you need to server your static files build with `ember build --prod` and as fallback you always serve the ember `index.html` file, so ember can boot up and the ember router can decide what to do then.

---

The other way is to integration ember in your asp.net MVC project. This is absolutly possible, but you should do this only if you understand both, the `ember-cli` build pipeline and the asp.NET project structure very well. If you do this you would have to do a lot of things yourself that are handled by `ember-cli`.

For example you would need to transpire ES6 to ES5 yourself, and you could not use any `ember-cli` addons out of the box. Also you would probably need to compile your templates, and implement a custom resolver.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, sorry, I'm not really good at the MVC part. I think I don't need to create an API because the data is ready as they told me, backend part has been done by someone else and must be returning a JSON, but how am I gonna get this data on ember exactly? I don't get what should I write to the `.js` file I created as a model, and how to call this JSON data in it. Thanks.

Comment: @HandeBc well you would modify a existing adapter like the `JSONAPIAdapter` or `RESTADAPTER`, or write a new one, and then call your ember app with `ember serve --proxy=http://backend/`.